# How to triger event on sms sending by default sms application in android os

Tags: android

i want to put check on sms sending, 
sms sending by default sms application of android os. 
is there any kind of event of `OnSendSMS`. like other events e.g. **on text change**, **onclick** etc.
i m new in android plz help me out with this. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a BroadcastReceiver as below,

```
public class checkSMSSending extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SEND_SMS"))
        {
            System.out.println ( "SMS Sent" );
                // Place your code here.
        }
    }
}
```